# Search text in JSONField

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

I use `peewee` with `SQLite`. One of my models contains the `JSONField` ([docs link](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#JSONField)) and now I need to query all rows where this field contains my string.

```
class Market(Model):
    ...
    data = JSONField()
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

If I try the following code, nothing returns:

```
Market.select().where(Market.data.contains(search))
```

Example data:

- `Market.data`: `['123', '456', '789']`
- `search`: `456`

How to find all rows where `Market.data` field contains the `search` text?

Comment: Please update your question with the output you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite json1 extension doesn't provide a "contains" function. You probably would want to use the `json_each()` or `json_tree` table-valued functions:

https://sqlite.org/json1.html#examples_using_json_each_and_json_tree_

Sqlite json1 extension docs:

https://sqlite.org/json1.html

Peewee sqlite json1 extension docs:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#sqlite-json1